# In mobile site Opera Mini select all the links of list items at once, any solution?

Tags: html, css, opera, mobile-website, mobile-phones

I'm making a mobile site for old mobile and testing on *Nokia 5130 Xpress Music* which has Opera Mini Browser.

The problem is when I have links list on a web page opening in Opera Mini and I try to select one link of the list, but it select the all list items instead of single.

Code of list

```
<ul id="nav">

                <li id="nav-1"><a href="#"><span>Nyheder</span></a></li>
                <li id="nav-2"><a href="#"><span>Kalender</span></a></li>
                <li id="nav-3"><a href="#"><span>Job</span></a></li>
                <li id="nav-4"><a href="#"><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
                <li id="nav-5"><a href="#"><span>Fa Svar</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *feature* of Opera; they have always highlighted all links that go to the same target when any one of them is selected.

(Maybe not *always*, but I remember fondly loving this feature on Opera's desktop browser roughly a decade ago, and I still love this feature on Opera Mini on my BlackBerry for years. I wish more browsers would do this, I find it a wonderful browsing aid.)

You could make all your link targets go to different locations. If they are actually different contents, that would make most sense to me.

Comment: +1, the links should really provide a non-javascript way to get to the same content.